# npm publish causes 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ...', errno -4048

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish, npmjs

I'm trying to publish my NPM package: `npm publish`.

I get the following quite cryptic error:

```
npm ERR! path c:\Temp\npm-20936-b98f84c8\tmp\fromDir-02dd5394\package.tgz
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\Temp\npm-20936-b98f84c8\tmp\fromDir-02dd5394\package.tgz'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\Temp\npm-20936-b98f84c8\tmp\fromDir-02dd5394\package.tgz'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\Temp\npm-20936-b98f84c8\tmp\fromDir-02dd5394\package.tgz'
npm ERR!        at Error (native)
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: 'c:\\Temp\\npm-20936-b98f84c8\\tmp\\fromDir-02dd5394\\package.tgz' },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'c:\\Temp\\npm-20936-b98f84c8\\tmp\\fromDir-02dd5394\\package.tgz\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'c:\\Temp\\npm-20936-b98f84c8\\tmp\\fromDir-02dd5394\\package.tgz' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Tried running as admin - same error.

NPM version: 5.4.0

Node version: 6.11.1

OS: Windows 10

Any leads?

Comment: I just want to add that this issue can also crop up on Windows if you're utilizing a Gradle script *without* excluding ".gradle" within your .gitignore file...or attempting to add any sort of lock file when running the npm pack/publish command.  I just chased my tail for 12 hours trying to figure that one out.  See here for more info: https://nigglingaspirations.blogspot.com/2020/09/the-npm-pack-command-works-fine.html.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Silly me. The answer was in the docs [all along](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages).

In order to publish you need to be logged in from your NPM cli.

So either do `npm login` if you already have a user on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com), or `npm adduser` to create one.

I would, however, appreciate a more informative error message.

Comment: Oh GOD! It worked on my side. I was logged in long time on my main computer... But got this error, because I've changed the password, so.. Thanks! Logging in again worked!

Comment: What a terrible error message! We managed to get this working by including out private npm repo details a the .npmrc file

Comment: I didn't find that in the docs, though it is something kind of obvious to do first.

Comment: Yes, npm login solved this problem. Misleading message information!

Comment: definitely a better error message is needed! I just struggled a bit with this on a new PC :)

Comment: I get this error when trying to publish a scoped package to our organization's repository (VSTS) not to npm.

Comment: How is this related to a permission error when attempting to delete a folder?

Comment: @Amnon - the correlation is not entirely clear to me as well. A better error log is definitely needed.

Comment: @vaiden the syscall unlink means a deletion of a file or directory is attempted.

Comment: @Amnon yeah but I'm not clear on the correlation with the authentication (login) status.

Comment: Neither do I. Moreover, I don't think it is related to login at all. I think something is locking the file or directory. Possibly the IDE or my employer's antivirus.

Comment: In most people's case - it is due to the authentication. A login solves it in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows.

The source of the problem is simple, it is access permission on folders and files. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540521/npm-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my experience.

I was working on Atom, and did file drag drop on Atom, it cause error.
So I exit atom on Win10 and run `npm i` again. It was successful.

Please turn off your editor or explorer which can restrict your project files and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to the new filesystem by remounting my windows drives. After that no problems anymore. Refer to the following [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is a matter of pointing to the correct `package.json` file. Had omitted the param in the before, causing the error.

Before: `npm publish`

After: `npm publish C:\Code\my-proj\dist\@acme\my-package`

Answer (score 0):

People who are still struggling, check your package.json file if you have something like
publishConfig initialized.
Deleting this is what solved for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was incorrect param `npm publish --opt=123456` (typo opt => otp ... one time password - 2factor). Terrible this misleading permission error `The operation was rejected by your operating system.` in case of wrong params.