# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink when running npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm

When running `npm publish` I get the error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\U173769\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8604-f99ed410\tmp\fromDir-f7379123\package.tgz'
```

I am using Windows 10 and tried running as administrator, but I get the same error.

I'm using `npm@6.4.1` and `node@v10.15.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm publish causes 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ...', errno -4048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090032/npm-publish-causes-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-errno-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use `npm login` or `npm adduser`.

Comment: But I am publishing to a local Verdaccio instance and not the public npm repository. Do you really need to log in? That's a bit unnecessary imo